# twilio send function parameter from a function to another function

Tags: function, parameters, twilio

i want to whisper a voicemail record to a callee,I used Dial.Number and using url I am redirecting to "another function" which will play the record as whisper .
so, I need to pass a parameter in the url,which will be retrived in that "another function", But when I send parameter in url it says invalid  URL format. this is the url [https://xxxx.twil.io/rec?RECSID=${rec_sid}](https://xxxx.twil.io/rec?RECSID=$%7Brec_sid%7D)

Here record_sid was passed as function parameter from twilio studio run function widget.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    for (let key in event) {
    console.log('1');
console.log(`${key}: ${event[key]}`);}

let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
twiml.say("functioon joe is  runnong");

 var rec_sid = event.record_sid ;
console.log('${rec_sid}');
const dial = twiml.dial();
dial.number({
                url: 'https://xxxx.twil.io/rec?RECSID=${rec_sid}'
               
             }, '+1207869');


 callback(null, twiml);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks for JavaScript template literals.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: console.log('${rec_sid}'); this is printing  exactly ${rec_sid} in console, can you please help me telling,why isn't it printing the value of the parameter send to the function?

Comment: is it possible to send parameters to the called function like this formatting of url https://xxxx.twil.io/rec?RECSID=${rec_sid}' ?

Comment: Yes, but use backticks and make sure `rec_sid` has a value. You should not need to `urlencode` the parameter.

Comment: a '+' sign seems doesn't go as %2b, I think in that case url encoding is needed

Comment: Ok, why would the Recording SID have a + in it?

Comment: sorry,I was mentioning all parameters in general,in that case phone numbers have + sign